# Why isn't my javascript function pulling text from text areas?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I would like to take the text from two text areas and insert them concatenated into a following paragraph. I've made a calculator and odd/even validator, and had been able to draw the user input values just fine. Is there something different with text?

```
<p>
<textarea id="text1" rows="4" cols="50">Type here!</textarea>
<br>
<textarea id="text2" rows="4" cols="50">Now type something here!</textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="tafunc()">Click here to put text in paragraph below!</button>    
</p>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function tafunc() {
    var first, second, bothtextareas;
    first = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    second = doucment.getElementById("text2").value;
    bothtextareas = first.concat(" ", second);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = bothtextareas;

}


</script>
```

Comment: I am voting the question down because the questions was answered and then changed accordingly, this is no longer the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document is misspelled in second assignment. and using value attribute for textarea is correct!

HTML:

```
    <textarea id="text1" rows="4" cols="50">Type here!</textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea id="text2" rows="4" cols="50">Now type something here!</textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1" type="button">Click here to put text in paragraph below!</button>    
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
```

change your inline javascript to this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn.onclick = function () {
    var first, second, bothtextareas;
    first = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    second = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    bothtextareas = first.concat(" ", second);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = bothtextareas;
}
```

and here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4hz0p8j/1/)

Comment: What is the advantage of placing onclick in the script vs in the button?

Comment: The advantages are:

1 - behaviour (javascript) is separated from presentation (HTML)
2 - no mixing of languages and a clean HTML
3 - you're using a javascript that can handle most cross-browser issues for you
4 - You can add behaviour to a lot of HTML elements at once without code duplication